# QImage doesn't seem to load any images at all (always returning null)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm on Windows7 and using Qt SDK 4.8.
Trying to read a file in with QImage but it just doesn't seem to load. That is, QImage(filename) or QImage(filename, "PNG") or QImage.load(filename) always return NULL.

Here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Open Image"),
                                                    QDir::homePath(),
                                                    tr("Image Files (*.png *.tga *.bmp)"));

    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        targetImage = new QImage(fileName, "PNG");
        if(targetImage->isNull())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this,
                                     tr("PhotoChop"),
                                     tr("Cannot load %1.").arg(fileName));
            return;
        }

        onScreenImage.setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
        onScreenImage.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
        onScreenImage.setScaledContents(true);
        onScreenImage.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*targetImage));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what file name is returning ? full path , relative path ?

Comment: fileName returns the full path. But I even tried the example that comes with the SDK (ImageViewer) and the QImage in that example does the exact same thing, that is, neither does it load the image (also returning full path). And I've tried with a couple different images

Comment: Have you tried any other formats?  I had trouble with PNGs and Qt because my (Linux) system had a newer version of the PNG library, and it couldn't use it.  I think it needed v1.2.

Comment: Yeah.. tried png, tiff and gif. Also tried the whole "static plugin" but I get either unresolved symbols or that it just can't open the libs.. for now, I got rid of QImage all together and am now using windows' gdiplus, at least it allows me to to get the raw bitmap for processing and a win HBITMAP handle with which I can initialize the QLabel.setPixmap()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has to do with how QImage loads "plugins" for reading files in. One option is to enable these plugins (for different file formats) and then linking against them.

Though instead I just used Gdiplus::Bitmap (from windows) to load in the file and then, from that, created an HBITMAP which QPixmap can use.